# I want to disable the button if specific text has been found in any label

Tags: javascript, innertext

I want to disable the button if specific text has been found in any label. 
The following code doesn't run because `aTags[i].innerText` is not equal to searchText all the time which is wrong because the label has inner text = "a" and the searchText variable have "a" as text - I need it to run in IE

```
<html>
    <script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
            var searchText = "a";
            var found;

            for (var i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++) {
                if (aTags[i].innerText == searchText) {
                    document.getElementById('choose').disabled=true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("failed")
                }  
            }
        });
    </script>

    <label> a </label> <br/>
    <label> b </label> <br/>
    <label> c </label> <br/>

    <input type='button' value='choose' id='choose' />    
</html>
```

Comment: So you want to remove the spaces?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2HC6s/44/ Demo

Comment: `if (aTags[i].innerText.trim() == searchText) {`

Comment: $.trim is safer than ....trim()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there should be easier ways to do that with jQuery

```
$(function () {
    var searchText = "a";

    $('#choose').prop('disabled', function() {
        return $('label').filter(function(_,el) {
            return $.trim( $(el).text() ) === searchText;
        }).length > 0;
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HvFfZ/1/)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your label contains `" a "` (with the spaces), but you're comparing with `"a"` (no spaces).

If you want to ignore the spaces, you can use jQuery's `$.trim(...)` to trim the text off the `innerText`.

But as you're using jQuery, you can *dramatically* reduce that code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var searchText = "a";
    var found = false;
    $("label").each(function() {
        found = $.trim($(this).text()) === searchText;
        if (found) {
            return false; // No need to keep looking
        }
    });
    $("#choose").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using jQuery, you can do what you like with much less complexity. 
This will work:

```
(function ($) {
    var searchText = "a";
    $('label').each(function(){
        if ($.trim($(this).text()) === searchText) {
            $('#choose').prop('disabled', true);
        } 
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: pretty much same solution as T.J's

Answer (score 0):

You have to trim label's text. Try with:

```
if (aTags[i].innerText.trim() == searchText)
```

or without `trim` method:

```
if (aTags[i].innerText.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '') == searchText)
```

Comment: I wouldn't rely on `String#trim` (which is relatively new to the standard) if IE support is an issue. I'd use jQuery's `$.trim` (as the OP is using jQuery...sort of.)

Comment: Actually I'd use `if ($.trim(aTags[i].innerText).indexOf(searchText) > -1)`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've added an alternative solution with regex.

Comment: It is jQuery so $.trim() is the better one since IE<9 does not understand trim, and innerText is also not understood by as many browsers as .text()

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match if a substring exists you can try with

```
aTags[i].innerText.indexOf(searchText) > -1
```

instead of

```
aTags[i].innerText == searchText
```

Comment: It allows for `"fooo a bar".indexOf("a")`

Comment: Well yeah, that's what substring means. If you need whole string match then remove the spaces and do what you already did.